# Finding cycles in a graph

Tags: algorithms

Given a directed weighted graph $D = (V, A, w)$ with weight function $w \colon A \to [0,\infty)$ and a source vertex $s$.  How can I find, for each vertex $v \in V$ a shortest (with respect to $w$) cycle that contains both $v$ and $s$ (it is allowed to repeat the same arc in a cycle).

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Did you manage to create a brute force algorithm?

Comment: Did you try running a shortest path from $s$ to $v$ and back again?  Why would you use the same arc twice?  Are you sure it's not the vertices you are allowed to reuse?

Comment: What do you mean by "source" vertex? Usually a source denotes a vertex with no incoming edges, which will never be in a cycle in a digraph.

Comment: @jmite OP probably means that $s$ is a designated vertex and simply wants to find a set of minimum cycles for each $v \in V \setminus \{s\}$ containing $s$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

Find the shortest path from every vertex to every other vertex. To find the shortest cycle from $s$ to $v$, just concatenate the shortest path from $s$ to $v$ and then $v$ to $s$ which was found earlier